# What happened to these tokens?

Tags: metamask, transfer, erc-20-approve

I send some Matic token in one of my wallets to the other for cover fee of a transaction (0.05)matic
but as soon as transfer succeeded, this amount transferred to another address, without any approval or anything.

here, is my wallet transactions :
https://polygonscan.com/address/0x1204D7F27702d793260Ad5a406dDEE7660d21B61

you can see my last 2 transactions and check what happened to this amount.
im happy because this amount actually is nothing, but i'm curious about what happened exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You let your phrases or private key vulnerable. Someone has a script running 24/7 in a way that everytime your account receive a deposit of ETH or specific tokens it will be transfered to this address there. Start a new wallet.

Comment: I don't think so, also its happened for me before, when i send some another matic from my first wallet to another wallet? in this theory ,when i send some matic to an address, after that, reception wallet transfer it another address, so it looks problem was about my sender wallet, but i have some matic in my sender wallet and nobody transferred them till now.

Comment: i think it's kind of malware that change somethings in approval or transfer message

Comment: Check this address where you matic went, follow his other transactions.